# Script throwing "write error: Interrupted system call"

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

I have a script that throws the above error, and typically on the same line, but at a different point in the running of the script.

Unfortunately I cannot run a simple find as I need a script that can be reviewed an implemented accordingly.

The aim of the script is to delete all files in specific, named, directories and there sub directories if the file is older than a specific age (x).  If all files in the folder are over x then remove the folder.  The command required must be output to a file for each of the main directories, such that the output can be reviewed before being run.

I have included a part of the script below which is the cause of the error.  The error typically occurs on echoing at the beginning of the function.  But on different loops.

```
finddir () {

echo "Entering finddir"
folder=$1
parentfolder=$2

echo $folder
echo "parent " $parentfolder
echo "$folder (parent $parentfolder)"



 dircount=`find $folder -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '1'  | wc -c` # checking for directories
 if [ $dircount -eq 0 ] && [ ! -z $parentfolder ] ; then

    modifiedseconds=`stat -c %Y $parentfolder`
    modifieddate=`stat -c %y $parentfolder`
    if [ $modifiedseconds -lt $testseconds ]; then
            echo "All files in folder $parentfolder to be deleted"
            disksize=`du $parentfolder --max-depth 0|cut -f1`
            filecount=`ls -1 $parentfolder|wc -l`
            echo "rm -rf $parentfolder    #$modifieddate | $disksize | $filecount" >>$deletionfile
    elif [ `find $parentfolder -type f -printf '1' | wc -c` -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "empty directory being deleted $parentfolder"
            echo "rmdir $parentfolder" >>$deletionfile
    else
            echo "finding files for $directory"
            findfiles $directory
    fi
else
    #find $folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d|
    while read folder2
    do
echo "Looping through folders"
echo "folder " $folder
echo "folder2" $folder2
            finddir $folder2 $folder
    done < <(find $folder -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
fi
}
```

Any thoughts on the root cause, or better ways to structure the script that will allow the code to run.

Thanks for reading

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Please add `set -x` to the top, run it a few times, and see what that tells you about the neighborhood of the failure. I suspect that  just writing the output of find to a temp file and reading it will be more stable than the use of <().

Comment: Thanks, and should have done that first to help
So the echo "parent" is showing in the output which is valid, but the error is appearing before the echo is actually echo'd

So I get 
echo 'parent' nameoffolder
...writerror.....

I am now assuming that bash is not handling the recursive function, but can work out why given its simplicity.